# how to play multiple video on demand with Wowza

Tags: wowza

I'm working on Wowza, it's a pretty awesome video streamer, but I have already setup a video on demand on that, but also I want to put more video on the Wowza. Can someone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In Wowza you create an application for streaming directory's content so you can stream any file within the selected location. Please specify what exactly is the problem you try to solve and what you mean by "put more video".

Comment: Cool, yes, it can play any video in the /content folder, I just tried. but the test player confused me, it can only allow me to type in one URL.

Comment: If you refer to continuous playback of files, one by one, then try Wowza's scheduled playback http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-%28ServerListenerStreamPublisher%29

Comment: It should be noted that the link in the above comment by @Aquary has moved to https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-schedule-streaming-with-wowza-streaming-engine-streampublisher